# Unable to run lambda in docker image

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, webpack, aws-lambda

I currently have an AWS Lambda that I've been working on that I would like to build and run from a docker image. I'm using the `aws-lambda-node:16` image as my base image. But I can't seem to get the docker image to properly pick up the handler from my javascript file to run the lambda.

I have tested the lambda's execution outside the docker image with [lambda-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local) and the lambda runs fine in my local environment. It just seems that something is up with the docker container.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:16

COPY dist/blacklist-ips/app.js ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

RUN npm i -g pnpm && pnpm install --production

CMD [ "app.handle" ]
```

My Webpack config:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';

import { default as webpack } from 'webpack';

import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';

const config = (env: any, argv: any): webpack.Configuration => {
  return {
    mode: env.production ? 'production' : 'development',
    entry: {
      'blacklist-ips': resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'blacklist-ips', 'blacklist-ips.ts')
    },
    output: {
      path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: '[name]/app.js',
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    devtool: false,
    target: 'node',
    externals: [
      '@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs',
      '@aws-sdk/client-wafv2',
      'luxon',
      'tslib'
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: [ '.ts', '.js', '.json' ]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /.ts$/,
          loader: 'ts-loader'
        }
      ]
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: env.production,
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          parallel: true,
          terserOptions: {
            mangle: false
          }
        })
      ]
    }
  }
}

export default config;
```

My handler function is being properly exported in the webpack bundle:

```
const handler = async () => {
  ...lambda logic
};
exports.handler = handler;
```

I'm stumped as to why it's not working correctly with the Docker container...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CMD` is `app.handle` while your function name is `handler`. You should change the `CMD` to be `app.handler`.